# Как правильно прописать Сервис в манифест файле?

Tags: android-service, android, java

Одно приложение (под Андроид) вызывает Service, сделанный в отдельном проекте.

`startService(new Intent("myServ1").putExtra("name", "value"));`

Сначала запускаю Сервис, все удачно. Потом запускаю прогу, жму на кнопку и получаю ошибку.

Вот лог:

```
01-15 13:29:24.702: W/ActivityManager(482): Permission Denial: Accessing service ComponentInfo{ru.servicekillserver/ru.servicekillserver.MyService} from pid=1220, uid=10086 requires android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE
01-15 13:29:24.706: W/dalvikvm(1220): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0xa4cacb20)
```

Мне кажется, что то-то не так в manifest файле. А что именно, не понимаю.
Ниже часть манифеста:

```
<service android:permission="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE" android:name="MyService">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="myServ1"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: вроде бы все правильно... Пробовали на разных устройствах?

Comment: Не очень понятно, что делает ваш сервис. Вообще указанный в логах пермишен используется для спел-чекера. В документации говорится:

>Applications with a spell checker service must declare the BIND_TEXT_SERVICE permission as required by the service. The service must also declare an intent filter with <action android:name="android.service.textservice.SpellCheckerService" /> as the intent’s action and should include a <meta-data> element that declares configuration information for the spell checker.

Comment: вот вам пример AndroidManifest.xml    
https://gitorious.org/rowboat/packages-inputmethods-latinime/source/a063ccb00e9d8bd983fdb797528d6de5517ac47e:java/AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте не в свойство тега сервиса прописать разрешение, а внутрь тега манифеста:

```
<manifest>
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BIND_TEXT_SERVICE" />
...
</manifest>
```

Comment: попробовал, не помогло. Eclips ругается, говорит что так нельзя.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб, этот пермишен в uses-permission никогда не прописывается.

Comment: прекратите пользоваться Эклипсом, если вы начинаете разрабатывать и никогда не пользовались им ранее, то советую перейти на Android Studio, пока еще не поздно.

Comment: @metalurgus, я просто на кофейной гуще гадал) Чтоб не путать людей надо удалить или просто в коммент преобразовать? =)

Comment: Помогло, если внутрь тега манифеста.
Огромная благодарность.